# C++ Как перегрузить метод так, чтобы при вызове из списка (родительского) вызывался дочерний метод

Tags: c++, list, перегрузка-операторов

Я бы хотел чтобы дочерние структуры были в списке с общим типом чтобы позже вызывать для них метод с похожим именем(и аргументами) но разными реализациями

Через `virtual` и `override` не получильсь:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Parent {
    virtual void say() {
        cout << "parent say\n";
    }
};

struct Child : Parent {
    void say() override {
        cout << "child say\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Parent a[2];

    Child x;
    a[1] = x;

    a[0].say();
    a[1].say();
    return 0;
}
```

На выходе:

```
parent say
parent say
```

То есть тут я хочу изменить метод `say` только у `a[1]`. Или так нельзя? Ведь имя и аргументы те же

Comment: У вас присвоение объекта типа `Child` объекту типа `Parent` (не ссылок или указателей!), происходит **срезка** (slicing) (про*гугл*яйтесь сами в Интернете, что это такое) и никакой виртуальности тут нет и не будет.

Comment: Массив `Parent a[2];` может хранить только `Parent`-ов, не потомков. `std::unique_ptr<Parent> a[2] = {std::make_unique<Parent>(), std::make_unique<Child>()};` сработало бы, или аналогично с сырыми указателями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это назывется **полиморфное наследование**, которое реализуется через **upcasting** производного класса к базовому. Но такие методы должны быть виртуальными, т.е. должна быть создана *виртуальная таблица методов* (**vtable**). *Upcasting* происходит неявно для ссылок и указателей:

```cpp
Parent parent;
Child child;
Parent* array[2] = {&parent,&child};
for (auto element : array) element->say();

Parent& ref{child};
ref.say();
```

Answer (score 1):

При копировании **Child** объекта новому объекту типа **Parent** не меняется тип нового объекта, он как был **Parent** так и остался. Происходит копирование только базовой части аргумента.
Виртуальные вызовы будут работать только если порождённый объект спрятан под указателем или ссылкой базового типа.

```cpp
  Parent p = x ; // p - это новый объект Parent
  p.say();  

  Parent & l = x ; // l - это ссылка на реальный Child
  l.say();
```